Blazor app throws AuthenticationFailureException if Google login is cancelled
I have Sign In With Google working fine with my Blazor server-side-app. The only problem is that if the user cancels on Google's sign-in page, my app throws AuthenticationFailureException. Here's the endpoint that initiates the login. I tried adding the try/catch here, but the catch section is never hit. This entire method finishes running before the Google sign-in page is shown.
endpoints.MapPost("/PerformGoogleLogin", (
    HttpContext context,
    [FromServices] SignInManager<ApplicationUser> signInManager) =>
{
    try
    {
        string requestedRedirectUrl = GetRequestedReturnUrl(context);

        IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, StringValues>> query =
        [
            new KeyValuePair<string, StringValues>("ReturnUrl",
            string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(requestedRedirectUrl) ? "/defaultUrl" : requestedRedirectUrl),
        new KeyValuePair<string, StringValues>("Action", ExternalLogin.LoginCallbackAction),
    ];

        var redirectUrl = UriHelper.BuildRelative(
            context.Request.PathBase,
            "/ExternalLogin",
            QueryString.Create(query));

        var properties = signInManager.ConfigureExternalAuthenticationProperties("Google", redirectUrl);
        var results = TypedResults.Challenge(properties, ["Google"]);
        return results;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Error in PerformGoogleLogin: {ex.Message}");
        throw;
    }
}).AllowAnonymous();

My ExternalLogin page implements OnInitializedAsync but that never gets called.
The URL in the browser is "https://localhost:7115/signin-google?error=access_denied&state=xx" so I tried creating a handler for /signin-google but that doesn't get hit.
Here are the raw exception details shown on the exception page:

Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationFailureException: An error was encountered while handling the remote login.
---> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationFailureException: Access was denied by the resource owner or by the remote server.
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.RemoteAuthenticationHandler`1.HandleRequestAsync()
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddlewareImpl.Invoke(HttpContext context)

How do I catch AuthenticationFailureException so I can show the user a "login failed" page instead of a developer exception page?

I'm not sure why moderator @blackgreen deleted the answer that I accepted and awarded bounty to. It seemed like a perfectly valid answer. It definitely solved my problem. Maybe it was a mistake? Basically, the advice was to supply a value to options.AccessDeniedPath in the call to services.AddGoogle.
